# Upgrading RAM in a Compaq dc7900 dual core 64bit system.

Tags: windows-7

I want to upgrade my RAM as computer is freezing and going slow from time to time I have Win7.

Not sure which RAM to purchase though.  I have 2 x 512 MB and 1 x 1024MB, plus one empty slot.

Not too technical please - I am a senior and a female to boot!

Cheers

Comment: Please update your question with more details of your PC, It will be better if you can share model/serial number.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath - It's mentioned Compaq DC 7900 ... in the subject itself.

Comment: @Pankaj : I got confused when I look into the datasheet http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04290693

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar and / or with locating the PC#-##### numbers on the sticks of RAM themselves (like **PC3-10600**)  could you provide that, If you are not comfortable messing directly with the sticks to locate that

you can open up **control panel** and select  **Device manager** and you should see **System Settings** and a read out of the PC's specs including this info..  Sadly just any ram is RARELY the solution.

(Image of that screen below)

[image: Windows System Info Panel]

Comment: Looks like a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

According to crucial's website the dc7900 has two slots of DDR2 PC2-6400 Unbuffered NON-ECC ram. Plus it supports a maximum of 8GB.

Given DDR 2 tends to max out at 2gb per stick,  your best bet is to buy a 4gb DDR2 "kit" which will have two 2gb sticks in it and use those.

Should cost around $50.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I now have a better idea of what to look for.   Cheers